# mysql script no database selected

Tags: mysql, command-line

I'm trying to run some mysql scripts from the command line. One is autogenerated and it does not select the database before hand. Right now I have two scripts:

```
mysql -u <user> -p<password> < script1.sql
mysql -u <user> -p<password> < script2.sql
```

the last line of script1 is `USE mydatabase;` but when I run script2 it says there is no database selected. Is there a way to specify what database to use for script2?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

add the parameter -D like this

```
mysql -u<username> -p<password -D<database> < script.sql
```

Answer (score 5):

```
mysql -u <user> -p<password> my_database_name < script2.sql
```

In your case happens because these are 2 separate processes and the queries from the first are not connected the ones from the second.

Another solution is to put `USE database_name` as first line in script2.sql

Answer (score 1):

The solution by @Desislav would work (other solution is to add '`use database`' command at top of `script2.sql`), but to clarify your issue

*the last line of script1 is USE mydatabase;*
This would not help for `script2`, since `script2` would be executed in a different process, you have to specify the database again.

Answer (score 0):

Under `*nix` (Unix, Linux, etc) you can use the `cat` command to combine the two scripts.

```
cat script1.sql script2.sql | mysql -u <user> -p<password>
```

Under DOS/Windows you can a little known feature of the  `copy` command

```
copy script1.sql+script2.sql | mysql -u <user> -p<password>
```